# Bind docker container port to eth0 WITHOUT giving a specific IP address

Tags: docker, networking, containers, puppet

I see that I can simply do `docker run -p SOME_IP_ADDRESS:25:25` to bind containers to a port on some interface, but let's say that I am using puppet to spin up multiple instances that have docker launching containers and I don't necessarily know what the IP of the instance's interface is going to be, then what?

For example, Inside the `/etc/systemd/system/SOME_APPLICATION.service` is my `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 0.0.0.0:25:25 SOME_CONTAINER` command so when the instance is spun up, docker will start up my container.

I don't know what the exact IP of the instance will be so I do not know which IP address should be passed into the `docker run -p SOME_IP_ADDRESS:25:25`.

Is there a way to do something like `docker run -p eth0:25:25` so that whatever IP eth0 has will be the IP address for the container port binding??

Comment: Do the hosts have multiple network interfaces?  Is there a specific reason you don’t want “all interfaces”?

Comment: @DavidMaze some hosts have multiple interfaces and I want containers restricted to eth0.

Comment: Maybe your automation system knows the IP address?  I’m not really familiar with Puppet but I know there’s Ansible syntax to inject the IPv4 address of the `eth0` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to use puppet's core facts https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_epp.html

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p <%= $facts[networking][interfaces][eth0][ip] %>:25:25
```